# Availability of kivy launcher application source code

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm doing some tests here and I was wondering if you guys know if the kivy Launcher source code is available ??? I searched the official website and github but did not find the application code that is on google play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's combined with the rest of the java code in https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/build/src/main/java. There's also an updated non-Java replacement at https://github.com/kivy/kivy-launcher.